# How to get details of Transaction ID (txn_id) from Paypal?

Tags: php, paypal

I am working on Paypal integrations on one of my websites

But the issue is that IPN is delayed by a few minutes most of the times

Users are redirected back from Paypal to my website with `txn_id`

What I want that I am looking for an API where from I can verify if transaction is valid or not

I tried https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/checkout/orders/ and https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/reporting/transactions?transaction_id=transaction-id but it gives me

```
{"name":"RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND","details":[{"issue":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","description":"Specified resource ID does not exist. Please check the resource ID and try again."}],"message":"The specified resource does not exist.","debug_id":"123","links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","rel":"information_link","method":"GET"}]}
```

But if I search that transaction-id from https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/activities page I can see the transaction

I created the token using my seller account.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use a server integration, so you capture from your server at checkout time and have an immediate API notification of success/failure, along with the transaction ID directly from PayPal.

Create two routes, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return JSON data. The capture call to PayPal, if successful, will have the transaction ID in the response -- which you can record as successful in your database before sending your JSON response.

The approval flow to pair with the above two routes: is https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server